# Obtain Click information before page changes in Google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, event-tracking

For doing event tracking, I am using the Click variables from Google tag manager to check which ID/Text I should use to create as a trigger.
I set GTM into preview mode and then go to my website to capture the gtm.click stage and see in there what the Click ID is.

[image]

However, when I want to track the Click ID being taken from a link that changes the page, I lose the data in the preview of GTM as a new page is loaded.
Does anyone know how can I either keep this information or specifically stop the page switch once the gtm.click event is registered in the preview?

Comment: On a Mac I use the quick workaround and hold the left alt key when clicking - this downloads the linked page and the current page stays put, but the events are still triggered and I can read the data in the variables tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of workarounds:

1) The solution mentioned by @Eike Pierstorff for Mac. In Chrome on Windows, you can hold `Ctrl` and click the link

2) Open developer console in your browser and execute this code:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank'); 
}
```

This code will set modify all links with `target=_blank` attribute. Then you can just click on links normally